# OnClickListener getting called twice in Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I have the following use case: when clicking on a `View`, it should open an `Activity` and when long clicked, it should open a different `Activity` after a time which is minimum of, 300ms or user's `ACTION_UP` event. 
I have written the following code for this:

```
holder.fiveAction.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //open activity A after launching an animation of 300ms
                isLongPressed = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
        holder.fiveAction.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                // We're only interested in when the button is released.
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // We're only interested in anything if our speak button is currently pressed.
                    if (isLongPressed) {
                        //open activity A even if animation hasn't ended
                        // Do something when the button is released.
                        isLongPressed = false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        holder.fiveAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LogUtil.i(TAG, "hi five onClickListener called");
                //open some activity B or do some work
        });
```

The issue with this setup is that the `OnClickListener` gets called twice which I don't want. I want to know why is this happening and how can I fix this without compromising my use case.

Comment: Why you don't use setOnLongClickListener()?

Comment: Will the default onLongClickListener suffice for your use case? Don't see a reason to introduce onTouchListener here.

Comment: @FarshidABZ If I only do long click, then activity would open only after the animation is finished. My use case is, if long press is registered and even if the animation is running and has not finished, if the user releases touch, it should open the activity.

Comment: @Egor the default long click listener won't suffice because I need to detect `ACTION_UP` too.

Answer (score 4):

You use three `Listener` 1.`OnLongClickListener` 2.`OnTouchListener` 3.`OnClickListener`

When you click on the View First it call OnTouchListener and then OnClickListener
That's why your event fire twice..

### Use This Trick I am sure you problem will solve ...... I test it myself

```
    holder.fiveAction.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //open activity A after launching an animation of 300ms

            holder.fiveAction.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
               public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                 // We're only interested in when the button is released.
                 if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // We're only interested in anything if our speak button is currently pressed.
                    //open activity A even if animation hasn't ended
                    // Do something when the button is released.

                 }
              return false;
             }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });

    holder.fiveAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LogUtil.i(TAG, "hi five onClickListener called");
            //open some activity B or do some work
    });
```

You need to declare `holder.fiveAction` as `final`

Comment: will `onClickListener` always be fired whenever `onTouchListener` is fired?

Comment: can click anything without touching that? You use 'MotionEvent.ACTION_UP'. Here is same thing if you touch anything you must have to UP your touch. So in this case all time two event must fired.

Comment: Any workaround for this? I want click and long press both to work normally.

Comment: You want, When you Click it open ActivityB and when longClick it open  ActivityA after 300ms and show some animation  but if you release Click or KeyUp then it don't wait and Open ActivityA. Ritght?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because of the buggy Android Debugger, when run normally the function got called once, with the debugger connected it got called twice.